# Openpose demo finishes with coredump in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: opencv, openpose

-Enviroment
OS : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
CPU: Intel corei7-10870H
GPU: Nvidia RTX-3070

I'm trying to proceed to set up openpose in Ubuntu20.04 with reading official document.
Finally I could succeed in passing through `make j8`
As a next step, I executed openpose demo with `./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --video examples/media/video.avi` but it failed with coredump.

After I faced this problem, I googled this problem and found this is an OpenCV problem.
Therefore I changed opencv version 4.2.0 to 3.4.15 because OpenCV-3.X is compatible.(According to openpose/doc/installation/0_index.md)

But I still get this error.
Is there any option for solving this problem?

Output is below

```
Starting OpenPose demo...
Configuring OpenPose...
Starting thread(s)...
Auto-detecting all available GPUs... Detected 1 GPU(s), using 1 of them starting at GPU 0.
F1002 14:49:47.953946 63080 cudnn_conv_layer.cpp:53] Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (1 vs. 0)  CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fa4976e51c3  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fa4976ea25b  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fa4976e4ebf  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fa4976e56ef  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7fa4972e40f5  caffe::CuDNNConvolutionLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x7fa4973c8e4d  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7fa4973cb365  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7fa497d9f48c  op::NetCaffe::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fa497db912d  op::addCaffeNetOnThread()
    @     0x7fa497dba33f  op::PoseExtractorCaffe::netInitializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fa497dbece5  op::PoseExtractorNet::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fa497db6af7  op::PoseExtractor::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fa497db2327  op::WPoseExtractor<>::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fa497de5227  op::Worker<>::initializationOnThreadNoException()
    @     0x7fa497de5378  op::SubThread<>::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fa497de6b88  op::Thread<>::initializationOnThread()
    @     0x7fa497dea16c  op::Thread<>::threadFunction()
    @     0x7fa497a24de4  (unknown)
    @     0x7fa497727609  start_thread
    @     0x7fa497863293  clone
Aborted (core dumped)
```